# Start home replacement app by pressing home button while on lock screen

Tags: android, android-homebutton

I have written a home replacement app that listens to the HOME-Intent and is started whenever the user presses the home button on the device.

This works fine if the phone is unlocked. But if the lock screen is shown and my home replacement app is not running anymore, a press on the home button will not start my application.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: I don't understand - you say "which is what I do". So you already display your app even though the screen is locked?

Answer (score 0):

No that is what the lock-screen is doing - locking your phone and preventing it from responding to the buttons.

It wouldn't be a lock-screen if it responded the way you are suggesting.

Perhaps if you write your own custom lock-style application, which would behave similar to a lock-screen.